localparam for case values with don't cares. Is 1'b? legal?
Can you replicate, concatenate a '?' literal somehow?  It seems my tools accept it.
Most direct answer: Section 3.5 Numbers of 1364-2005 has a stanza for 'z_digits'. z_digit ::= z | Z | ?, so it is fine to use either '?' or 'z' as they are equivalent.

I have a list of bits.  The text 'EV#' is some appropriately named event.  Like ON_HOOK, OFF_HOOK or whatever.  Several events are arriving and the intent is to prioritize the translation and insertion to a fifo.  My initial coding transposition to stackoverflow has some errors which have been corrected.  The code here is intended to be minimal example.  Apologies for any confusing in the editing/transposition here.

localparam BIT_EV0 = 0;
localparam BIT_EV1 = 1;
localparam BIT_EV2 = 2;
localparam BIT_EV3 = 3;
localparam BIT_MAX = 4; // Register size.

reg [BIT_MAX-1:0] event_queue;

I would like to define a case constants such as,
`define CASE_VALUE(bit) {{BIT_MAX-bit-1{1'b0}}, 1'b1, {bit{1'b?}}}
localparam [BIT_MAX-1:0] PRI_EV0 = `CASE_VALUE(BIT_EV0);
localparam [BIT_MAX-1:0] PRI_EV1 = `CASE_VALUE(BIT_EV1);
localparam [BIT_MAX-1:0] PRI_EV2 = `CASE_VALUE(BIT_EV2);
localparam [BIT_MAX-1:0] PRI_EV3 = `CASE_VALUE(BIT_EV3);
`undef CASE_VALUE

So that I can construct,
 casez(event_queue)
   PRI_EV0: ;
   PRI_EV1: ;
   PRI_EV2: ;
   PRI_EV3: ;
   /* etc. */
   default: ;
 endcase

Events are set/cleared with event_queue[BIT_EVx] = 1'b0; Now, I have to explicitly type the case constants and update all of them when adding and removing a new event bit. Prior was written without the understanding that 1'b? may exist.  The case labels have actions which are not numerically constructed.  They aggregate data for a destination message queue/fifo.
Interestingly, I can use a local parameter like,
localparam [BIT_MAX-1:0] PRI_EV2 = 4'b01??;

So the only issue is specifying a '?' constant, which seems to work with 1'b?, but I was not aware that this was a language construct and had never seen it mentioned in replication and concatenation.  It tried to trace the 2001 standard and got stuck with 'constant_expression'.
I am trying to restrict to Verilog-2001.

@toolic: Yes. Verilator, iverilog, and questa do not complain and simulation is the same as constants.  Note: I first wrote 'case', but it is 'casez' (updated).  Quartus synthesizes (but I have not tested this yet).

You should use casez to support wildcards. You can use z to represent the don't care bits.
IEEE1364-2001 § 9.5.1 Case statement with don’t-cares

Don’t-care values (z values for casez, z and x values for casex) in any bit of either the case expression or the case items shall be treated as don’t-care conditions during the comparison, and that bit position shall not be considered.

Equivalent statement in latest SystemVerilog IEEE1800-2023 § 12.5.1 Case statement with do-not-cares
Tested with iverilog on EDAplayground https://www.edaplayground.com/x/DxKz
module tb;
  localparam BIT_EV0 = 0;
  localparam BIT_EV1 = 1;
  localparam BIT_EV2 = 2;
  localparam BIT_EV3 = 3;
  localparam BIT_MAX = 4; // Register size.

  reg [BIT_MAX-1:0] event_queue;


  localparam [BIT_MAX-1:0] PRI_EV2 = {{BIT_MAX-BIT_EV2-1{1'b0}}, 1'b1, {BIT_EV2{1'bz}}}; // z for wildcard


  always @* begin
    casez(event_queue)
      PRI_EV2: $display("in PRI_EV2 with event_queue=%b", event_queue);
      /* etc. */
      default:  $display("in default with event_queue=%b", event_queue);
    endcase
  end

  integer i;
  initial begin
    for(i=0; i<2**BIT_MAX; i=i+1)
      #1 event_queue = i;
    #2 $finish;
  end

endmodule


Alternate solution if one priority bit is expected is to use case(1'b1)
case(1'b1) // Note: inline synthesis priority/parallel flag may be needed
  event_queue[BIT_EV3]: ; // highest priority
  event_queue[BIT_EV2]: ;
  event_queue[BIT_EV1]: ;
  event_queue[BIT_EV0]: ; // lower priority
  default:  // catch-all , lowest priority
endcase

I see in the LRMs case(1) should work the same as case(1'b1). My experience over the years with a several Verilog simulators is case(1) always hit the default condition. The case(1'b1) works as expected on all simulators.

I guess it is normal to use 'z'.  But is it legal to have 1'b? as a constant?  I am not sure that 1'bz is clearer.  I am not checking for high z, I want to say it doesn't matter.  Is 1'bz equivalent to 1'b??

@artlessnoise I added IEEE references for 1'b? vs 1'bz and an alternative solution
